# How to get all Hive account delegators using Python

Tags: python, blockchain

The Hive Condenser and other AppBase API has account specific functions to get outward delegation methods such as `get_vesting_delegations` and `get_expiring_vesting_delegations`, but nothing *yet* for inward delegations.

There are available and tested SDKs such as BEEM, but it is too bulky for a small project. I'd like to directly access of the Hive APIs / JSON RPC nodes to get inward account delegations.

TAGS: hive-blockchain hive-api blockchain dpos python

Answer (score 0):

Since Hive is a blockchain, technically all information should be accessible to anyone and is readily accessible using the official Hive APIs. We can use the `condenser_api.*` to get all account transactions using the `get_account_history` [method](https://developers.hive.io/apidefinitions/#account_history_api.get_account_history).

The JSON RPC results can be further narrowed down through the method's parameters:

- account: string
- start: int (-1 for reverse history or any positive numeric)
- limit: int (up to 1000)
- operation_filter_low: int (optional)
- operation_filter_high: int (optional)

The tricky part here is the 128-bitmasking of the [Operation IDs](https://gitlab.syncad.com/hive/hive/-/blob/master/libraries/protocol/include/hive/protocol/operations.hpp), which can come *not so* straightforward to some new developers.

Just check the Operation ID found in `operations.hpp` link above and use the Operation ID as the length of zeroes for the bit-string. For the example below, it is 40+1, since we are doing `ljust`.(`total_string_length`, `character`) then cast the bit string back to integer.

```py
operation_id = 40  # delegate_vesting_shares_operation
operation_filter_low = int("1".ljust(operation_id+1, "0"), 2)
```

Use the resulting value to the `operation_filter_low` parameter and continue formatting the payload before sending the request. It is best to create a *util* function to preformat the parameters, payload, and the API call for an added reusability.

```py
# formatting the parameters
username = "hivehealth"
start = -1
limit = 1000
params = [username, start, limit, operation_filter_low]

# preparing the payload
request_id = 1
method = "condenser_api.get_account_history"
payload = { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": method, "params": params, "id": request_id}
```

Create the API call function. Check all the Hive [Witness Nodes](https://developers.hive.io/quickstart/#quickstart-hive-full-nodes) and create a node list to loop over, then breaking after completing the request operation.

```py
NODES = ["api.hive.blog"]
def _send_request(session, headers, payload, timeout=60):
    response = None
    for node in NODES:
        try:
            url = "https://" + node
            if None not in auth:
                response = session.post(url,
                                        headers=headers,
                                        json=payload,
                                        timeout=timeout)
                break
        except:
            print(f"\nNode API '{node}' is offline, trying the next node....")
    if response is None:
        return []
    
    response.raise_for_status()
    try:
        response = json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8"))
        if "result" in response:
            return response["result"]
    except:
        pass
    print(f"\nNode API response from '{node}' is unusable....")
    return []
```

The function will return a list of lists and can be accessed using a loop.

```json
[[4, {'trx_id': '1c453a97c10daff1c27161ec6f9d4f4566b54896', 'block': 55496700, 'trx_in_block': 42, 'op_in_trx': 0, 'virtual_op': 0, 'timestamp': '2021-07-09T16:37:39', 'op': ['delegate_vesting_shares', {'delegator': 'giftgiver', 'delegatee': 'checkit', 'vesting_shares': '30000.000000 VESTS'}]}]]
```

To run it all, below is the sample code:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

def delegations():
    """ Get all Hive inward delegations. """
    
    # Prepare session
    session = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.5, status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504])
    session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    headers = { "User-Agent": f"CustomAPI v0.0.9", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }

    # formatting the parameters
    username = "hivehealth"
    start = -1
    limit = 1000
    params = [username, start, limit, operation_filter_low]

    # preparing the payload
    request_id = 1
    method = "condenser_api.get_account_history"
    payload = { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": method, "params": params, "id": request_id}

    transactions = send_request(session, headers, payload, timeout)

    ## customize this part as needed
    delegators = {}
    for transaction in transactions:
        delegation = transaction[1]["op"]
        delegator = delegation[1]["delegator"]
        if delegator not in delegators:
            delegators[delegator] = {}
        timestamp = transaction[1]["timestamp"]
        # can optionally be { delegator : vesting }
        # but changes in delegation can be important at times
        delegators[delegator][timestamp] = float(delegation[1]["vesting_shares"].split(" ")[0])
    return delegators
```

That's all, you can now make narrower requests on account history using the code above. Just make sure to optimize the code and make other variables dynamic as needed.